# Haskell GADT and Deriving Show

Tags: haskell, gadt

How can I make `show` work for the `Bind` data constructor?
The first two (`Return` and `Put`) seems to work fine.
Since `Bind` takes a function as argument I figured It need some special "treatment"?

```
data Program a where
  Put    :: Char -> Program ()
  Get    :: Program (Maybe Char)
  Return :: a -> Program a
  Bind   :: Program a -> (a -> Program b) -> Program b

instance Show a => Show (Program a) where
    show (Return a) = show a
    show (Put a) = show a
    show (Bind pr f) = show pr   -- incorrect


• Could not deduce (Show a1) arising from a use of ‘show’
  from the context: Show a
    bound by the instance declaration at EDSL_Deep1.hs:18:10-35
  Possible fix:
    add (Show a1) to the context of the data constructor ‘Bind’
• In the expression: show pr
  In an equation for ‘show’: show (Bind pr f) = show pr
  In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Program a)’
```

Comment: This can't really be done in a good way. It's generally not possible to show functions, and in this case `Bind` also makes you lose track of the `Show a` constraint. So, better just forget about it.

Comment: If you want to show `pr` in this case (because hope is essentially lost for showing the function), you could include the show dictionary in the GADT. `Bind :: (Show a) => Program a -> (a -> Program b) -> Program b`.  However you will lose the ability to instantate the standard `Monad` class if you do, because it requires unconstrained variables.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be mixing up your type variables. The `a` in `Program a` has no relation to the `a`s in the types of constructors. It's just there to specify the kind of Program. In fact with `KindSignatures` you can say `data Program :: Type -> Type` just as well. While we're at it lets also rename vars in Bind, because we can:

```
data Program :: Type -> Type where
  Put    :: Char -> Program ()
  Get    :: Program (Maybe Char)
  Return :: a -> Program a
  Bind   :: Program x -> (x -> Program y) -> Program y
```

This is still the same definition. Hope this makes it clear that you're trying to show `Program x` having only `Show y` and that's why you get the error. As said in the comments I don't think there's hope here.

Comment: Put another way, the type variables are implicitly scoped to the constructor’s signature, as `Bind :: forall x y. Program x -> (x -> Program y) -> Program y` (and you can write it that way explicitly). I prefer to write them out, name them distinctly, or use a kind signature for this reason, particularly in potentially confusing cases like `data a :~: b where Refl :: a :~: a` vs. `data (:~:) :: Type -> Type -> Type where Refl :: forall x. x :~: x`.